# How to make flex spacing depend on window width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flex spacing to make my figures be spaced equally, but when I shrink window they go beyong parent section.

HTML part:

```
        <section class="features">
        <figure>
            <img src="Images/Vanilla-Cupcakes.jpg" alt="Homemade Vanilla Cupcakes">
            <figcaption>Homemade Cupcakes</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="Images/mini-cinnamon-rolls.jpg" alt="Sweet Cinnamon Rolls">
            <figcaption>Cinnamon Rolls</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="Images/christmas-bread.jpg" alt="Christmas Sweat Bread">
            <figcaption>Christmas Desserts</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
```

CSS part:

```
.features {
background: bisque;
color: white;    
padding: 20px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: row;
}
.features figure {
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
width: 350px;
}
.features figure img{
border-radius: 10px;
width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to happen on narrower viewports. You have fixed the width of items, do you want them to go one below the other when the viewport is narrower. Or do you want them to each shrink in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.features { flex-wrap: wrap }
```

It wraps the content when there is not enough space.

Comment: One of figures is now always wrapped and it does'nt change no matter what width windows is

Comment: Add `.features { flex-wrap: wrap }`. Remove `350px` on `.features figure`  and `.features figure img` and add `.features figure { flex: 0 0 20%; }` and `.features figure img { max-width: 100%; }`. That is a quick solution for your specific problem, but as A Haworth was asking above - what is your goal?

Comment: So i fixed problem with flex-warp by adding meta tag. My goal is to make spaces between figures proportional to window width, so that when i shrink a page spaces get narrower

Comment: Try `.features { justify-content: space-between; }`

Comment: This one works, thanks

Comment: Great! I recommend this funny and educating course on flexbox if you want to deepen your knowledge: https://flexbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

This is because the text is too big at one point. You could either try to create a fluid font-size or try to break the text with the word-break css property. I also would recommend not to use fixed widths inside your flex items (350px)